# What's the syntax for writing to files with SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to write to a text file, and I'm using the example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) but I can't figure out how to add text to it?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     Stream myStream ;
     SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

     saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"  ;
     saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
     saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;

     if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         if((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
         {
             // Code to write the stream goes here.
             myStream.Close();
         }
     }
 }
```

I've changed `// Code to write the stream goes here.` to a couple of things, like:

`string thing = "This gets written";`

and

`"This gets written";`

But that didn't work and I have no other ideas :L

Comment: Seriously? You can't Google "write text file c#"? It's even worse than I thought: You know you have a `Stream`, so just RTFM on Streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(myStream))
{
    writer.WriteLine("File content goes here");
}
```